# What language is best for opening huge files?

Tags: passwords

I'm working on a new password generator, and I need to use large word lists in order for it to work.  Word lists could be like 30-40mb and while I would like to use PHP for it, I don't know if it will be the best solution.  I need a language that deals with opening large files and scanning them.  Is C is the best option? How can I make it web accessible, if so?

If a person chooses a password of length 16 it should "randomly" choose 2-4 words adding up to that length, so I'm not sure if it would be necessary to store the entire file into memory (doesn't sound very efficient)

Thanks.

Comment: Interesting.  I assume this is based on http://xkcd.com/936/ right?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to store all those words in a database and then access them from there?

Comment: @DavidStratton Yes.  It just dawned on me how much sense this makes, as the majority of the passwords I use for things are 16-32 characters in length of alternating lower/upper case with symbols and I have to use a password management program(KeePass) which is protected by a master password which I also have written down and it just seems a bit ridiculous.

Comment: I know this isn't helping your quesiton, but this is really interesting to me.  Just out of curiousity, have you ran the idea past the Security.stackexchange.com site yet?  I'd be curious to know what the security experts think of the approach.  I'm not sure if I think it's good or not, but it sure is an interesting one.  It's worth investigating at any rate, and they know a lot more than I would about how easy/hard to crack such a system would be.

Comment: As a side note, I think this will likely get closed as "not constructive".  Almost every "what language is best" question does.  But @galaxyAbstractor is right - I think a database - any database would be better than a huge file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a language that deals with opening large files and scanning them. Is C is the best option?

You should actually probably store your words in a database.

> How can I make it web accessible, if so?

Any program can output html text.  Using C is a pain in the neck, but it can definitely be done.  See this question: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/132281/are-c-and-or-c-viable-practical-options-for-web-development